# Why are some entry detail views empty in the control panel?

Tags: control-panel, error-message

I can't seem to edit entry details all of a sudden: in this Products section (and *only* this one section), the page title and "Current Version" button will render, but the rest of the page is missing.

[image]

The only clue is this line from Craft's log:

> [31-Jul-2014 19:07:36 UTC] PHP Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in /Users/gob/projects/gobias/craft/app/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Node.php on line 140

I've loaded earlier MySQL backups, restarted MAMP Pro (PHP 5.5.10), cleared Craft's caches, tried different browsers and machines, and the problem persists.

Comment: Have you filed a bug through the dashboard widget? Looks like a bug to me...

Comment: Thanks @Marion—yes I did, and I'm actually asking here since Brad said it's come up before. Answer's on the way!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

That error isn't a Craft or PHP error, it's coming from older versions of [xDebug](http://xdebug.org/).

It can happen on more complicated pages (lots of fields, tabs, etc.), but you can get around it by adjusting the [xdebug.max_nesting_level](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#max_nesting_level) to something higher than the default 100 or to upgrade xDebug to 2.3+, which has changed to the default value to 256.

Note that you don't have to have an active debug session going on in order to run into this, you just have to have the xDebug extension installed.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I set it to 250 on a whim, and all's well again.

Comment: WHO DEBUGS THE DEBUGGERS?!

Comment: Philosophy majors.

Comment: programmer psychologists

Comment: I am having the same issue but I don't know where to edit the "debug.max_nesting_level" setting. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: @user3818623 it'll be in your php.ini file.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest solution is just to deactivate all debugger stuff in mamp's PHP settings -> **Uncheck: Debugger Activate Xdebug**.

Comment: That's the simplest solution provided that you're not using the debugger and/or never plan to.