# Blank entry input page

Tags: entries, control-panel

I can't edit my entries. The entry page has no input fields. See attachtment

[image]

I run the latest Craft version. Cleared the cache, tried different browsers.
No errors in my console.

It looks like that no javascript file is loaded on the page.

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: Yes. Nothing strange.

Comment: What plugins do you have installed? If there is no sign of anything fishy, I would send in a ticket with the logs through the support widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually when you see this, PHP is running out of memory trying to load the page.  Bump your php.ini file's [memory_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) setting to something higher and that should fix it.

**Update:**

Actually, this is in your phperrors.log file:

```
[23-Sep-2014 15:11:20 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!
```

See [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/why-are-some-entry-detail-views-empty-in-the-control-panel) for the fix.

Comment: My memory limit is 256M. Must be enough.

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Big hug for Brad!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it.  Increase the max_nesting_level to something like 200.  Add/edit the following line in your php.ini:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
```