# Blank entry page in CP

Tags: matrix, control-panel

I set a matrix block field for a blog's channel and when I try to create a new entry, It is empty

But if I change the matrix field with another field, it works.

Anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you got any other third-party plugins installed? Particularly look at if you are using a third-party field-type on that Matrix. Also, which version of Craft are you using?

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply :) Version: Craft Pro 2.3.2642

And Yes, I've third party plugin in field-type in Matrix

Comment: I'd suggest removing that third-party field, possibly un-installing the whole plugin and trying again. If that solves it, contact the plugin maintainer, but also I would suggest upgrading to the latest version of Craft as 2.3.x is quite old now.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue running OS X running native Apache.  It could be PHP config issue.  Increase the max_nesting_level to something like 200.  Add/edit the following line in your php.ini:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
```

Comment: Related: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/why-are-some-entry-detail-views-empty-in-the-control-panel/1560#1560