# Unable to edit any entry after update to 2.5

Tags: error

I can't edit any entry after updating to Craft CMS 2.5.2754 - what I see is attached.

PHP does not report any errors and other parts of the control panel and frontend seem to be working.

Before I dive deep - is there anybody who has had the same behaviour and was able to fix it?

The update has been done twice already, once automatically, once manually. Same results in both cases.

[image: Entry editation screen]

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed?

Comment: No plugins installed.

Comment: There should be something in your ``Craft.log``. Also check your browser's console/error log to see if it's trying to load anything and failing... It almost looks like there might be some files missing from the install...

Comment: I have exactly the same issue after upgrading to 2.5 :-/ I can't seem to find anything in the Craft/PHP logs that relate to it, and there's no errors in Chrome's developer tools.

Comment: See: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/why-are-some-entry-detail-views-empty-in-the-control-panel