# Fields not displaying for some entries in control panel

Tags: control-panel

Since I updated to Craft 2.5, I have a weird bug in my entry edition window. Some entries work just fine, and other gives me this :

[image]

Like if there was nothing (actually there is something, this single in particular has two tabs and many fields in each..)

Any fix ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have [xDebug](http://xdebug.org/) installed on your server, you're probably running into [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/why-are-some-entry-detail-views-empty-in-the-control-panel/1560#1560).

If you don't, you're probably running into [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/2777/57).

Comment: Thanks man ! It was indeed xDebug, had to comment it all in the php.ini to see it work.