# 'Create a new entry' CP is blank if matrix field exists

Tags: matrix, control-panel, entry

I set up an **matrix field** and put it into section type.

If I am trying to create new entry a kind of broken **'Create a new entry'** CP is shown up. Only title 'Create a new entry' and an broken 'save' button. Also rest of header seems not to rendered nice. Horizontal scrollbars appear.

If I change same field to other type, all works as expected.
It really only happens if I am using matrix field.

All happens on fresh setup:
No plugins installed. (Just this one task tried and failed).
Mac, Mamp Pro.
Craft (version 2.5.2757)

Console in Browser says nothing.

What I tried:
 + Fresh installation with user permissions for all craft folders read&write.
 + PHP memory config on 128mb. (Mamp Pro).

UPDATE: **SOLVED** It had something to do with php error settings in Mamp Pro. Once disabled, all is working, also with Matrix.

Comment: Would you mind adding that as an official answer instead of an edit to the original question?

Comment: Related: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/why-are-some-entry-detail-views-empty-in-the-control-panel/1560#1560

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Do it as in craft instructions asked '[PHP 5.3.0 or later with safe mode disabled](https://craftcms.com/docs/requirements)' and all works perfect like a charm.

This problem came from settings in Mamp Pro. The debugger was active. And all other 'what to log' too. After uncheck - no problem any more.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue here -- could be a PHP one.  I solved it by increasing the max_nesting_level to something like 200.  Add/edit the following line in your php.ini:

```
xdebug.max_nesting_level = 200
```