# Missing entries in admin panel

Tags: admin

My Craft admin panel is running fine locally but when I login remotely my entries aren't there. Do I need to change something in the config file?

Comment: Related? https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2765/matrix-field-input-error-from-within-the-control-panel and/or https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/why-are-some-entry-detail-views-empty-in-the-control-panel/1560#1560

Answer (score 3):

Are you accessing the same databases? You need to make sure that the local database has been uploaded to the remote server. Then all your entries should show up.

You can back up your local database by going to `/admin/settings` on your local machine. Then you'll need to upload that database to the remote server.

You can also learn more about setting up a [multi-environment config](https://craftcms.com/docs/multi-environment-configs) in the Craft documentation.

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed to do.