# Matrix Fields translation not working

Tags: matrix, localization

I have the following problem:
My Craft site was setted up normally. I made entries with matrix structure and build one after another.

Then after i built a lot of entries i wanted to set up a second locale for the site.

So i used the craft manual on your site and i told the fields that i want to have in the second language as well that its translateable.

But now if i want to translate my matrix fields in the entry, THE HOLE matrix structure is gone :O but of course i do not want to create them new.

If i do ne entries now after setting up the second language, matrix fields are translateable, but not my entries that were exist before... How can i now fix it?
I read on different blogs that is a bug..

Please help me :)

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you've got xDebug installed and you're running into this: [Why are some entry detail views empty in the control panel?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/why-are-some-entry-detail-views-empty-in-the-control-panel/1560#1560)

Or your php.ini file's [memory_limit](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) is set to something low and you're running out of memory and it needs to be bumped up.