# How to recover lost entries

Tags: entries

Good afternoon. It would appear that i've lost all my entries! I still have the headings, but where I would have entries added (the pages i would edit on my site), i have nothing!

It is all still on my site thank goodness. Is there anyway I can recover this, Or revert back to a previous "backup" point as you would in windows?

Comment: Hi Jacqui! Could you please consider accepting Brad's answer if it was correct, or following up with your own answer if you solved the problem? Either way I hope you didn't lose content! :)

Answer (score 1):

Any chance you've got xDebug installed on the server?  If so, sounds like you're running into this: [Why are some entry detail views empty in the control panel?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/why-are-some-entry-detail-views-empty-in-the-control-panel/1560#1560)

If that's the case, your data isn't missing from the database, so there's no need to revert.  You just need to fix the underlying problem so the edit entry page can display properly.

Comment: I have the same problem; how do I get the "edit entry page to display properly"?